# React class component has property but Typescript says it doesn't

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having an issue with React ref and class component.

My simplified code is below. We see I have a component called `Engine` which has a property `getInfo`. I do a test of `this.activeElement &&` which means it is not `null` so it must be a `React.ReactElement<Engine>`. However Typescript compiler fails with error that this does not have property `getInfo` as seen in screenshot below.

```
class Engine extends React.Component {
    getInfo(count: number): void {
        console.log('info count:', count);
    }
}

class Wizard extends React.Component {
    activeElement: null | React.ReactElement<Engine>

    topLevelGetInfo(): void {
        this.activeElement && this.activeElement.getInfo(10);
    }

    handleRef = (el: null | React.ReactElement<Engine>) => this.activeElement = el;

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Engine ref={this.handleRef} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "build_test"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide inferred access to `getInfo` - `activeElement` should be asserted as type `Engine` (rather than `React.ReactElement<Engine>`) or `null`.

`activeElement` also requires an initial value of `null`, as `undefined` is not valid.

```
// Engine.
class Engine extends React.Component {

  // Get Info.
  getInfo(count: number) {
    console.log("Info Count:", count);
  }

  // Render.
  render = () => <div>Engine</div>;

}

// Wizard.
export class Wizard extends React.Component {

  // Active Element.
  activeElement: Engine | null = null;

  // Top Level Get Info.
  topLevelGetInfo() {
    const { activeElement } = this;
    if (activeElement) activeElement.getInfo(10);
  }

  // Handle Ref.
  handleRef = (el: Engine | null) => (this.activeElement = el);

  // Render.
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Wizard.
        <Engine ref={this.handleRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  // Did Mount.
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Mounting Wizard.");
    this.topLevelGetInfo();
  }

}
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much @Arman!! `Engine` is actually one of many components it can be. The component must have the `getInfo` property, and it gets some props injected. Can I do `React.ComponentType<{ prop1: blah }>` somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `Wizard` and `Engine` classes aren't extending from `React.Component`. Try updating your class declarations like so:

```
class Engine extends React.Component  {
 ...

 render() { return null; }
}

class Wizard extends React.Component {
  ...
}
```

Also, be sure to include the required `render()` method for your `<Engine />` component (ie as shown).

Here is [a working example on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/yp7pqmz4wx) - hope that helps :-)

Comment: Oops my mistake, I forgot the `extends React.Component` part when typing the simplification. I still have the issue :(

Comment: @Noitidart just updated answer with link to working demo - does this help?

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? In your dev environemnt, or on codesandbox?

Comment: @DacreDenny in both. Codebox and dev. I really appreciate you trying so I +1.

Comment: @Noitidart you're welcome, this is very strange because I don't seem to get any syntax errors when I run the codebox sample - just curious to know what your `tsconfig.json` file looks like - can you add that to your OP ?

Comment: Thanks @Dacre I added tsconfig.